# How can I create an index based on the year and month of a timestamp?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I'm trying to create an index based on the year-month of a timestamp field (e.g. `2018-03`).

Initially I tried doing:

```
create index tmp_year_mo on my_table
((to_char(DATE(ts_field AT TIME zone 'utc'), 'YYYY-MM')))
```

But unfortunately you get `ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE` because the function apparently has mutable output. This doesn't quite make sense to me as I thought I removed the variability of the output by setting the timezone to UTC (?).

Everyone else doing this who's posted about it has had a simpler problem like just converting using the `::DATE` cast, which is fine, but I need the year-month.

I guess a solution could be to create a whole new column in the table and then populate it with this value, and then index off it, but is there an expression that will work within the CREATE INDEX realm?

Comment: whats the data type of ts_field?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should work:

```
create index tmp_year_mo on my_table
((date_trunc('month',ts_field at time zone 'utc')))
```

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/f6b42095-5fe2-4f6a-8c49-6bd49badb3ad%40mm

> you can shift your timestamptz to a  fixed timezone

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC

Comment: The field is of type timestamptz - I tried your code and unfortunately it still shows the same error :/

Comment: sorry - a long day. of course you need to adjust tstz to a fixed value